# UWP long-running background tasks that can be published in the microsoft store

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, desktop-application

We are building a desktop UWP application that is used to show and store NFC information stored in embedded nfc chips inside our products. It has to be published in the microsoft store, for specific reasons which are not relevant.

We encounter that UWP doensn't really accept background tasks that are long-running and the sdk we must use to control the NFC reader doesn't have built-in support for UWP. The `deviceUseTrigger` out of scope. Using the `extendedExecutionUnconstrained` in the appmanifest wouldn't work either to the fact that it can't be published in the store.

What are our options? Must we build an external application that is started at startup and communicates of an tcp or namedpipe? Other technologies that fits better to developing desktop applications in this scenario

Comment: Have you considered using the [WinUI3((Windows App SDK))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/?tabs=net-maui%2Ccpp-win32) project?